# Trying to install asp.net on xampp

Tags: asp.net, apache, xampp

im trying to run aspx files on my xampp installation But the Apache Server doesn't Start.

What i did:

Installed a clean Xampp.

Installted the mod_aspdotnet-2.2.0.2006-setup-r2.msi

changed my httpd.conf:

```
#asp.net

LoadModule aspdotnet_module modules/mod_aspdotnet.so
AddHandler asp.net asax ascx ashx asmx aspx axd config cs csproj licx rem resources resx soap vb vbproj vsdisco webinfo 

<IfModule mod_aspdotnet.cpp> 
AspNetMount /SampleASP "C:\xamppASP\htdocs" 
Alias /SampleASP "C:\xamppASP\htdocs" 
<Directory "C:\xamppASP\htdocs"> 
    Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.aspx 
</Directory> 
AliasMatch /aspnet_client/system_web/(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/(.*) "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v$1.$2.$3/ASP.NETClientFiles/$4" 
<Directory "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v*/ASP.NETClientFiles"> 
    Options FollowSymlinks 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory> 
</IfModule>

#asp.net
```

After this steps the Server doesn't start anymore.

Even if i just run:

```
LoadModule aspdotnet_module modules/mod_aspdotnet.so
```

The Server doesn't start.

I already checked the Folder C:\xamppASP\apache\modules
The file exists.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that this:

```
AspNetMount /SampleASP "C:\xamppASP\htdocs" 
Alias /SampleASP "C:\xamppASP\htdocs" 
<Directory "C:\xamppASP\htdocs">
```

Should be:

```
AspNetMount /SampleASP "C:\xamppASP\SampleASP" 
Alias /SampleASP "C:\xamppASP\SampleASP" 
<Directory "C:\xamppASP\SampleASP">
```

That is, that you change your directory name to the one you give as 'SampleASP'.

Comment: If I only put the loadmodule line I have the same error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't start anymore is probably because the directory you set doesn't exist.

"C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v*/ASP.NETClientFiles"

I have been trying to get the same thing to work and I found that I don't have ASP.NETClientFiles, if you remove your changes it will start again.

Or if you figure out where ASP.NETClientFIles comes from and install that. Then it will work.