# ASP.NET on XAMPP server

Tags: php, asp.net, xampp

I have a xampp server running on windows 8.1. I have an ASP.NET application that I want to run local, in the htdocs folder (because I need interaction between PHP & ASP.NET).

Now I installed a ASP module, changed http.xampp.conf,... But when I try to start the apache server, It blocks, and I get an error (only that I need to look in the logs, no further information, even not in the logfiles).

I don't know what to do.. Someone that has experience with this?

Comment: (Classic) ASP and ASP.NET are very different things. If you want to use ASP.NET, I'd seriously look at using IIS instead of Apache.

Comment: It's ASP.NET.. Sorry for the misunderstanding in my post. 

I don't know IIS.. Have a look for it..

Comment: Seems it is the same problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137392/trying-to-install-asp-net-on-xampp

Unfortunately no answer :(

Comment: Installed IIS and it works smooth..